# Migrating from external source to AD

Tags: active-directory

I'm not even sure where to start so any info would be helpful.

My organization uses AD for authentication... and that's about it. All users are stored in a single OU and then under a group OU when appropriate and all under one domain. We don't use AD to track/store phone numbers, ext., dept., directors, etc. However, we have started using OTRS as our ticketing system and if you're familiar with it, it integrates nicely with AD to provide the ticket requester's info such as phone, ext., email, etc. Well, we keep all of that information in a third party system. Specifically, a product called inteli-desk.

I'm a dba guy not an AD guy (just enough to cause damage) so my question is: Is there a way/tool or something to migrate the information from the SQL Server db that inteli-desk uses and populate it in AD?

-Peter

Comment: This would be more suitable for serverfault site rather than dba.se.

Comment: question has been cross posted on serverfault.

Comment: You should have flagged this for move to serverfault instead of posting a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i will refer to Admin Guide [OTRS Admin Guide](https://otrs.github.io/doc/manual/admin/4.0/en/html/external-backends.html)

There is clearly stated that user data backend is divided from Auth module.

So...

1) Go to Config.pm

2) Set User Auth module to LDAP

```
   $Self->{'Customer::AuthModule'} = 'Kernel::System::CustomerAuth::LDAP';
   $Self->{'Customer::AuthModule::LDAP::Host'} = 'ldap.example.com';
   $Self->{'Customer::AuthModule::LDAP::BaseDN'} = 'dc=example,dc=com';
   $Self->{'Customer::AuthModule::LDAP::UID'} = 'uid';
```

3) Set user data backend accordingly to SQL Server (check that according DBI ODBC driver is installed)

```
$Self->{CustomerUser} = {
    Name => 'Database Datasource',
    Module => 'Kernel::System::CustomerUser::DB',
    Params => {
        # if you want to use an external database, add the required settings
#            DSN => 'DBI:odbc:yourdsn',
#            Type => 'mssql', # only for ODBC connections
#            DSN => 'DBI:mysql:database=customerdb;host=customerdbhost',
#            User => '',
#            Password => '',
            Table => 'customer_user',

            # CaseSensitive will control if the SQL statements need LOWER()
            #   function calls to work case insensitively. Setting this to
            #   1 will improve performance dramatically on large databases.
            CaseSensitive => 0,
        },
# customer unique id
CustomerKey => 'login',

# customer #
CustomerID => 'customer_id',
CustomerValid => 'valid_id',
    CustomerUserListFields => ['first_name', 'last_name', 'email'],
    CustomerUserSearchFields => ['login', 'last_name', 'customer_id'],
    CustomerUserSearchPrefix => '',
    CustomerUserSearchSuffix => '*',
    CustomerUserSearchListLimit => 250,
    CustomerUserPostMasterSearchFields => ['email'],
    CustomerUserNameFields => ['title','first_name','last_name'],
    CustomerUserEmailUniqCheck => 1,
#    # show not own tickets in customer panel, CompanyTickets
#    CustomerUserExcludePrimaryCustomerID => 0,
#    # generate auto logins
#    AutoLoginCreation => 0,
#    AutoLoginCreationPrefix => 'auto',
#    # admin can change customer preferences
#    AdminSetPreferences => 1,
#    # cache time to live in sec. - cache any database queries
#    CacheTTL => 0,
#    # just a read only source
#    ReadOnly => 1,
    Map => [
        # note: Login, Email and CustomerID needed!
        # var, frontend, storage, shown (1=always,2=lite), required, storage-type, http-link, readonly, http-link-target
        [ 'UserTitle',      'Title',      'title',      1, 0, 'var', '', 0 ],
        [ 'UserFirstname',  'Firstname',  'first_name', 1, 1, 'var', '', 0 ],
        [ 'UserLastname',   'Lastname',   'last_name',  1, 1, 'var', '', 0 ],
        [ 'UserLogin',      'Username',   'login',      1, 1, 'var', '', 0 ],
        [ 'UserPassword',   'Password',   'pw',         0, 0, 'var', '', 0 ],
        [ 'UserEmail',      'Email',      'email',      1, 1, 'var', '', 0 ],

#        [ 'UserEmail',      'Email', 'email',           1, 1, 'var', '$Env{"CGIHandle"}?Action=AgentTicketCompose&ResponseID=1&TicketID=$Data{"TicketID"}&ArticleID=$Data{"ArticleID"}', 0 ],
        [ 'UserCustomerID', 'CustomerID', 'customer_id', 0, 1, 'var', '', 0 ],

#        [ 'UserCustomerIDs', 'CustomerIDs', 'customer_ids', 1, 0, 'var', '', 0 ],
        [ 'UserPhone',        'Phone',       'phone',        1, 0, 'var', '', 0 ],
        [ 'UserFax',          'Fax',         'fax',          1, 0, 'var', '', 0 ],
        [ 'UserMobile',       'Mobile',      'mobile',       1, 0, 'var', '', 0 ],
        [ 'UserStreet',       'Street',      'street',       1, 0, 'var', '', 0 ],
        [ 'UserZip',          'Zip',         'zip',          1, 0, 'var', '', 0 ],
        [ 'UserCity',         'City',        'city',         1, 0, 'var', '', 0 ],
        [ 'UserCountry',      'Country',     'country',      1, 0, 'var', '', 0 ],
        [ 'UserComment',      'Comment',     'comments',     1, 0, 'var', '', 0 ],
        [ 'ValidID',          'Valid',       'valid_id',     0, 1, 'int', '', 0 ],
    ],
    # default selections
    Selections => {
        UserTitle => {
            'Mr.' => 'Mr.',
            'Mrs.' => 'Mrs.',
        },
    },
};
```

4) Start debugging, where is the error in configuration

Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks artjoman. But I already have it authenticating. My ad setup though lacks a lot of useful info so I want to migrate it from a third into ad. The cross post actually had some good info so I'll close this post